# Why is it fine to reference a contract type but not use it to create a new contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am going through the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#creating-contracts) and I have seen, in the code example given that:

```
// `TokenCreator` is a contract type that is defined below.
// It is fine to reference it as long as it is not used
// to create a new contract
```

Why can one not create a new contract from the contract type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's written that way in the docs.

If you have the contract source code (as is the case here), you can freely create new instances of it. It's just a matter of whether you *want to* do that (or whether you *should* do that).

My guess is that the doc is trying to say that "don't accidentally create a new instance of it when you just wanted to reference an existing one".